# Intel NUC 7i3BNK flickers and freezes immediately upon restart after installing graphics driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, hdmi

I have one (well three) of these new Intel NUC7i3bnk Kits. I tried to set them up and use them as workstations. I installed Windows 10 Pro Version 1703 from an USB stick, and so far, so good. The initial setup worked and I was able to login to the standard user and begin installing drivers. Or so I thought.

Every time I attempt to install a graphics driver, or every time I install an windows update (which somehow includes the graphics driver), the PC immediately freezes up and has to be hard-reset. When restarting after the hard reset, the login screen comes up as normal, but immediately begins flickering and freezes up 3-5 seconds afterwards, requiring another hard reset.

The only fix I've found so far is to not install the graphics driver and hard-disable windows updates, which is obviously unnaceptable.

What else I have tried so far:

- 3 different graphics driver versions: 15.45.16.4542, 15.45.16.4627 and 15.45.16.4664
- Installing a BIOS update to the latest BIOS V. BNKBL 357.86A.0046

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Other Hardware Specs:

- Samsung 960 EVO NVMe SSD 250GB
- 8GB PC4-17000 C15-15-15-36 Flash memory

Using a bog standard HDMI ready monitor and bog standard HDMI 2.0 compatible cable, as well as a generic microsoft keyboard and mouse.

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's not the problem. I can't even install the initial graphics driver, as mentioned in the question

Comment: ask this the INtel support. We can't fix their drivers. Try v1607 first and if this works stay on this build until Intel creates better drivers and Windows Update offers you v1703

Comment: @magicandre1981 I had hoped this wasn't a "just me" issue and maybe someone found a temporary fix somewhere. Guess intel support it is.